# list indices must be integers, not str error

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, syntax-error

With my little function here, i was trying to change my 10 digit integer phone number to word form. it gives me an error.

```
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    cake=list(phone_num)
    print(cake)
    for v in cake:
        if cake[v] == 0:
            cake[v] = "zero "
        elif cake[v] == 1:
            cake[v] = "one "
        elif cake[v] == 2:
            cake[v] = "two "
        elif cake[v] == 3:
            cake[v] = "three "
        elif cake[v] == 4:
            cake[v] = "four "        
        elif cake[v] == 5:
            cake[v] = "five "  
        elif cake[v] == 6:
            cake[v] = "six "
        elif cake[v] == 7:
            cake[v] = "seven "
        elif cake[v] == 8:
            cake[v] = "eight "
        elif cake[v] == 9:
            cake[v] = "nine "
```

thanks for any help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently iterating over a `list` of 1-character strings, and then trying to find out if that `list`'s element at that string index is equal to an integer. I'll demonstrate why that's nowhere near what you need to do by replacing the variables with literals:

```
def getWordForm('1234567890'):
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']=list('1234567890')
    print(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'])
    for '1','2',etc. in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']:
        if cake['1'] == 0:
            cake['1'] = "zero "
```

You have to index a `list` with integers. The characters in this phone number (which happen to represent integers) also have nothing to do with their index - you could have a `'9'` at index 3. You also aren't returning anything, so your function would run (if it could), end, and throw everything away.

Do this instead:

```
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    numbers = {'0':'zero', '1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three', '4':'four',
               '5':'five', '6':'six', '7':'seven', '8':'eight', '9':'nine'}
    return ' '.join(numbers[num] for num in phone_num)
```

The result is as expected:

```
>>> getWordForm('123')
'one two three'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you passed your number in as an integer then `list(phone_num)` is a error because `list()` expects an iterator and `phone_num` isn't an iterator.
If you passed in a string, then you are indexing a list using a character `cake[v]`.

It looks like you are wanting to iterate over the indexes (`range()`) and swap the value with it's word form, e.g.:

```
cake = list(str(phone_num)):
for v in range(len(cake)):
    if cake[v] == '0':
        cake[v] = 'zero'
    ...
return cake
```

You can also replace the whole  `for: if-elif-elif-...` block with a dictionary lookup and list comprehension:

```
word_form = {
    '0': 'zero',
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
    '3': 'three',
    '4': 'four',
    '5': 'five',
    '6': 'six',
    '7': 'seven',
    '8': 'eight',
    '9': 'nine'
}

def getWordForm(phone_num):
    return [word_form[d] for d in str(phone_num)]

>>> getWordForm(1235554387)
['one', 'two', 'three', 'five', 'five', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'eight', 'seven']
>>> getWordForm('1235554387')
['one', 'two', 'three', 'five', 'five', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'eight', 'seven']
```